# tastypie hook just before sql is exeucted

Tags: tastypie

I need to implement some database hints (mysql keeps using wrong index).
Im using tastypie and django.
is there any hook to override to modify sql just before it is executed.
Is there any way to integrate hints with tastypie?

Comment: Tastypie is only a layer over Django ORM. So you definitely should looking for Django solutions.

Comment: I've inherited a project and trying to issue a fix. I'm looking for a starting point. I'm afraid that finding a complex solution with the underlaying layer will be very difficult for me to integrate at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I am no good in databases. But I think Django in enough large project that include some tools for that unless its very very unique. Check these links: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques http://www.djangorocks.com/snippets/indexing-your-django-models.html